# Kafka 2 consumer factories listeners are not connected constantly

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are using Spring Kafka 2.1.4.RELEASE version in our project and we have the following configuration:

```java
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Configuration
    class ProducerConfig {
        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ASerializer.class);
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<String, A> producerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<String, A> kafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    class ConsumerConfig {
        @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
        private String groupId;
        @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset}")
        private String autoOffsetReset;
        @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit}")
        private boolean enableAutoCommit;
        @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records}")
        private Integer maxPollRecords;

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> firstConsumerConfig() {
            Map<String, Object> props = getCommonConsumerConfig();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ADeserializer.class);
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> secondConsumerConfig() {
            Map<String, Object> props = getCommonConsumerConfig();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, BDeserializer.class);
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<String, A> firstConsumerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(firstConsumerConfig());
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, A>> firsttContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, A> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(firstConsumerFactory());
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<String, B> secondConsumerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(secondConsumerConfig());
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, B>> outputTopicContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, B> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(secondConsumerFactory());
            return factory;
        }


        private Map<String, Object> getCommonConsumerConfig() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, enableAutoCommit);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
            return props;
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see we use 2 consumer factories. And we have following consumer class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties
@Service
public class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(containerFactory = "firstContainerFactory", topics = "someTopic")
    public void firstListener(@Payload A first) {
        //some logic
    }

    @KafkaListener(containerFactory = "secondContainerFactory", topics = {
     //topic list       
    })
    public void secondTopicListener(@Payload B second) {
       //some logic

    }


}
```

So what we are noticing during starting of this app is that it's not connected to both topics all the time. Sometimes it is connected only to the second topic or only to the first topic and possibly it might connect to the first and second topics (which is correct). So can you please help to understand what is misconfigured here?

Comment: What does it mean “connected”? Maybe you just suffer from the Kafka group management?

Comment: You should use a different `group.id` for each; otherwise a rebalance on one will affect the other.

Comment: It seems that your ProducerConfig will not be picked up by Spring, since it is not static.

Comment: it's actually picked up as it has Config annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally best practice to put each listener in a different `group.id` (you can use the `groupId` attribute on the `@KafkaListener` which overrides the consumer factory). Otherwise when the second one starts, a rebalance is caused on the first one. The current 2.1.x version is 2.1.10.

Comment: then can I assign different group ids to each of my consumer? or it's some of the kafka setups?

Comment: You can either set a different `group.id` in `firstConsumerConfig` and `secondConsumerConfig` (instead of a single value in `getCommonConsumerConfig()`), or you can specify them in the `@KafkaListener`.

Comment: gotcha, so that means that they will be assigned to different consumer groups, correct?

Comment: Correct and (assuming the topics are different) a rebalance of the topic/partitions on one listener will not impact the other.

Comment: so I assigned different group ids for them and issue is still present. So basically I renamed only one of them and left another one without changes. So the one which is not changed doesn't work. But if I rename it then I got all messages(including old ones) from that topic which is not good for me. But if I leave topic without changes for some time - after rebalancing consumer got connected to the topic. Why does it happen?

Comment: You will only get new messages; if you want to start from the beginning for an existing group, you have to perform seek operations on the topic/partitions. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#seek

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some more investigation I was able to identify what kind of issues happened on my side. So basically we have one consumer group with multiple topics. So in my case we had 0 partitions for each of these topics(as I understand there are no partitions and we operate with 1 queue of the topic). So when I'm connecting to that kafka instance - all consumers connected to those topics but when somebody also connects to that topics(probably my colleague) then re balancing is happening he starts listening to one of those topics instead of me(due to the fact that only one consumer can present per partition).